# Would it be possible to include the scicomp.SE site in the list of related SE sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

I came across a post that is in my opinion more about scientific computing, than mathematics. Therefore I wanted to flag the question accordingly, but I couldn't find the scicomp.SE site among the suggested. Would it be possible to include it there?

This question/suggestion in a "picture":

- Flagging

  - Needs improvement

    - Community specific

      - What site does this question belong on?

        - meta.math.SE
        - stats.SE
        - physics.SE
        - (would be nice to have this) scicomp.SE

Comment: It would be fine to leave a comment suggesting to the OP that they have a look at SciComp.SE, esp. if you link to a Question there that is closely related to what they are asking.  Unless you actively participate in another site (and it doesn't appear that you are involved with SciComp.SE), some caution is warranted in recommending that a Question would be on-topic there. A *flag* here should be used if a Question is off-topic, not merely to suggest it might be better handled elsewhere.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for your comment. Yes, that's quite alright. I have two concerns. Firstly, when I flag a post as off-topic, I think my flag is more useful if it indicates where the post would fit better. Expanding the list of sites should take no time. Is the counterargument that people would misuse this? Secondly, I think many smaller .se sites would greatly benefit from parts of this site's traffic without really hurting it.. posting to those should be encouraged, and I don't think a simple comment like you suggest is enough. Dare I say, I wouldn't mind expanding the list of off topics.

Comment: I left comments for the OP of the Question you linked below, explaining what would be required to make a software related request on-topic at Math.SE and pointing to a specific resource offered by the software vendor.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you truly think the question does not fit in on math.se and would be a perfect fit for scicomp.se, you can flag about it, but this occurs infrequently enough on math.se that including it in the related sites would not be practical. There are a number of other sites which we also don't include in the related list for the same reason.

Comment: I understand this site has a much longer history. Regardless, In my opinion users should be encouraged to choose more specific .se communities whenever possible. To me this is akin to tagging a question properly. I think listing the 5-10 most related sites on the flagging page would be useful in order to encourage this. The community obviously disagrees. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Andrew [SE limits the maximum number to 5, which 1 is always reserved for the child meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96345). While Maths.SE currently uses 3 of them, proposing a new migration target should be backed up by data (which high rep users and mods have access too) and ideally an agreement with the target site.

Comment: @AndrewT. I see, thank you for that thread. That was enlightening. The $5$ limit doesn't make sense to me either, but I can accept it. Given this limit I understand why the selection of these sites is problematic. Maybe then the top users should vote for the top 4 related sites every year, where 'related' is decided by data analysis? If you post your comment as a separate answer, I'll accept it as such, otherwise I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

There are currently several SE sites that are closely related to Maths SE:

- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) (technically not an SE site)
- [Mathematics Educators (Beta)](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)
- [History of Science and Mathematics (Beta)](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)
- [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)
- [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)
- [Mathematica & Wolfram Language](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)
- Some may even list Stack Overflow here.
- etc.

While they are supposed to be independent, there exist overlaps, if not many.

I consider these as *options* for users: they can choose the one that is more suitable for their question so that they can get a satisfactory answer more effectively. As long as a question is *on-topic*, the asker should have the freedom of choosing which site to use.

If someone posts an *on-topic* question on site X, while *you* consider it more suitable for site Y, instead of signaling a migration, it would be better if you leave a comment under the question such as "This question may receive more attention on the site Y."

If a question truly needs to be migrated from site X to site Y, it should be off-topic on X first (and hopefully users on site Y also agree that the question would be on-topic there). I believe such cases are rare and many off-topic questions are (usually) not very well written and thus may not be a good fit for migration to another site as well.

Comment: It's hard to avoid overlaps between math-related fields and mathematics. I agree, they should have the freedom of choice, but IMO picking a more specific community should be encouraged much more. Yes, one can comment something like "This question may receive more attention on the site Y.", but IMO that's not enough. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for your comment. Do you have a specific example in mind? As long as a post is *on-topic* I don't see a big problem of leaving it here. Users on site X may give very different answers to a question that is also suitable on site Y. Throwing an on-topic question away is not quite necessary and may very likely bring frictions.

Comment: [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655531/how-to-change-the-intergenartion-time-in-simevents-in-matlab) prompted me to ask, but there have been others in the past. It always bothered me to see only those 3 sites listed, but apparently this is fine with everyone else who visits math.meta.se, so I will have to live with it. :)